# Writing spark.sql dataframe result to parquet file

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, hdfs

I enabled the following spark.sql session:

```
# creating Spark context and connection
spark = (SparkSession.builder.appName("appName").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate())
```

and am able to produce see the results of the following query:

```
spark.sql("select year(plt_date) as Year, month(plt_date) as Mounth, count(build) as B_Count, count(product) as P_Count from first_table full outer join second_table on key1=CONCAT('SS',key_2) group by year(plt_date), month(plt_date)").show()
```

However, when I try to write the resulting dataframe from this query to hdfs, I get the following error:

[image: saving spark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame in hdfs]

I am able to save the resulting dataframe of a simple version of this query to the same path. The problem appears by adding functions such as count(), year() and etc.

**What is the problem? and how can I save the results to hdfs?**

Answer (score 3):

It is giving error due to '(' present in column 'year(CAST(plt_date AS DATE))' :

Use to rename :

```
data = data.selectExpr("year(CAST(plt_date AS DATE)) as nameofcolumn")
```

Upvote if works

Refer : [Rename Spark Column](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=rename)